# How do I ask how to authorise my scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a set of three Google Scripts, which occasionally require me to re-authorise them. 
I used to be able to do this, but I've lost this skill. 
Frankly, I've lost all my IT skills

I did manage to find my scripts, as projects, and I've attached an image of one of them.

How do I re-authorised these scripts?

[image]

Comment: Does this help? https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/how-tos/enable

Comment: Just click  the play button on top

Comment: I'm sure this is right, but I can't find my way back to seeing my script. I can see the list of my scripts, but when I open one, it doesn't  show the code, so I'm unsure what to do.

Comment: Ah, does the play button mean the same as run, a small triangular icon?

Comment: @Swifty No need  to submit anything. Click **Advanced** on the bottom left and accept the risks.

Comment: How about you take the 30 minute codelab intro? See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for more details.

Comment: I went into Advanced, but didn't see anything that I could do that was as simple clicking and accepting the risks. I'll try it again, but I might have forgotten how to get into "edit"

Answer (score 0):

Just about any function will do.  You can even use a null function `function donothing(){//do nothing};`  Your scripts are evaluated to determine what scopes you require and then generates an authentication dialog which you have to approve before going any further.  Sometimes, an error may occur and it will provide you with a scope that you may have to install in your manifest file and you will have to add an entry like this `"oauthScopes": ["https://scope_url/"]` to you manifest.

[manifests](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/manifests)

Answer (score 0):

I've now managed to re-authorise my three scripts, and they are working. I may have to re-authorise them again, but I've now documented what I have to do to get this done.
There may be more lasting ways to authorise the scripts, but I'm not going to fiddle with them whilst they are working.