# Can I make my Google script keep working without my interaction?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

Several years ago I created a set of three Google Scripts which allow me to delete my emails after set times. The times are like "delete after one month", "delete after a year" and "delete after 5 years".
The scripts worked perfectly for the first year, but then I had to re-activate them.

Then I contracted Alzheimers... I managed to keep things going for a couple of years, but now I can't work out how to re-active the scripts.

I suspect that I never managed to put my scripts into production.

Would someone help me to fix this problem I have.

Perhaps Gmail has a feature to delete emails automatically now?

If you can help me, remember that my IT skills are almost non-existent now, so you might need a lot of patience.

Comment: I'm happy to send you my 3 scripts so you can see how they all work.

Comment: I remember how I constructed the scripts; I drag the emails that I want to time out into a special folder, and then that folder automatically uses my script to delete the emails after the chosen time.

Comment: Maybe [your previous posts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5244024/swifty) like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60486883/how-do-i-ask-how-to-authorise-my-scripts) will jog your memory.

Comment: Can you just post your three scripts in your question.

Comment: It's hard to completely guarantee that a script will keep working without interaction due to the large amount of changes constantly being made.  The update before last of my gmail app made a change which caused all of my apps to stop working.  I assumed that they would fix it on the next update and they did.

Answer (score 0):

#### Delete all messages in a label:

You will need to enable Gmail API.  If you have never done that you may require some assistance.

```
function delEmailsInALabel() {
  let ts = GmailApp.search('label:enter label here');
  let ids = [];//array of message ids
  if(ts && ts.length > 0) {
    ts.forEach(t => {
      let ms = t.getMessages()
      if(ms && ms.length > 0) {
        ms.forEach(m => {
          ids.push(m.getId())
        });
      }
    });
  }
  var request = { "ids": ids };//message ids to delete
  console.log(ids);
  Gmail.Users.Messages.batchDelete(request, "me");//This is irreversible
}
```

Comment: I don't remember enabliing the Gmail API. Is there a test I could do?

Comment: If you never enabled Gmail API then your scripts never deleted emails because GmailApp cannot delete emails in can only put them into the trash

Comment: In order to enable  Gmail App you need to go to services in the new editor and click the + and select the Gmail API and you will also need to go the cloud console or whatever it's called these days and enable it there.  I suspect that you may need assistance doing this.

Comment: A test would be if my script fails on the last line.